# Modifying an ExecuteSQL statement in FileMaker Pro to allow for day leniency

Tags: sql, filemaker

I am trying to alter a statement in a long script that sets a variable to the result of an exact match of a couple variables. Right now it's an exact date match, I want to have it to match if the dates are off by ~2 days, before or after. The current script is:

```
Let( [
   UUID = sqlNameField( EIV_Eiv::A__UUID ; "" ; "" )
; BATCHID = sqlNameField( EIV_Eiv::A_BATCH_ID ; "" ; "" )
; PID = sqlNameField( EIV_Eiv::User_ID ; "" ; "" )
; STARTDATE = sqlNameField( EIV_Eiv::Start date ; "" ; "" )
; EIV = sqlNameTable( EIV_Eiv::A__UUID ; "" )
] ;
  ExecuteSQL( "SELECT" & UUID & "," & BATCHID & "FROM" & EIV & "WHERE" & PID & "= ? AND" & STARTDATE & "= ? FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY" ; ¶ ; "" ; EIM_Eim__SELECTED::User_id ; EIM_Eim__SELECTED::Start_date )
)
```

I tried modifying to the `ExecuteSQL` line to:

```
ExecuteSQL( "SELECT" & UUID & "," & BATCHID & "FROM" & EIV & "WHERE" & PID & "= ? AND" & STARTDATE & "- ? >= -2 AND" & STARTDATE & "- ? <= 2 FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY" ; ¶ ; "" ; EIM_Eim__SELECTED::User_id ; EIM_Eim__SELECTED::Start_date )
```

To no effect (and FMP won't return any kind of errors that I can see). Am I tackling this the right way? I'm fairly new to FMP scripting and I'm amateurish with SQL.

Comment: @Kubie Hmm that might be against the site policies... I can't in good faith down-vote a good answer either! :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't try to do math on the dates columns in the SQL directly, but rather do it in the FileMaker parameters you pass. (Also, there seemed to be some spaces missing that I added)

Something like this:

```
ExecuteSQL( "SELECT " & UUID & "," & BATCHID & 
" FROM " & EIV & 
" WHERE " & PID & " = ? AND " & STARTDATE >= ? AND STARTDATE <= ? FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY" ;
"¶" ; "" ; EIM_Eim__SELECTED::User_id ; EIM_Eim__SELECTED::Start_date - 2; 
EIM_Eim__SELECTED::Start_date + 2 )
```

Comment: Hmm it didn't work, but this makes a lot of sense with the syntax now... I'll keep messing around with it. This definitely needs a couple more quotation marks in there around `STARTDATE`, since it's just a variable in this situation.

Comment: Not entirely sure what that custom function sqlNameField is doing, but as long as those varables are defined in the current context, and it looks like they are, they look right to me. FileMaker will insert their values. Debugging SQL can be hard, but there are several ways to make it easier. 1. Prepare the whole SQL statement in a variable that you can inspect in the data viewer for any syntax error. 2. Call a wrapper function with your SQL to get a proper error message, like sql.debug, available [here](http://www.fmfunctions.com/fid/335).

Comment: I noticed a couple of missing spaces and have added them.

Comment: By the way, this was essentially the solution. All that was missing was some type conversions.